# Formatting Discord Bot Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm dabbling with Python and JS trying to making some specific commands for a Discord Bot.
I'm running some into some issues formatting what I want it to look like. Does anyone by chance know what I'm missing?

Goal: Add index values in front and an indent before the username. Also, add a line spacing between each entry.

```
@bot.command(name='qs', aliases=['showqueue'], help='Show the current queue')
async def queue_show(ctx):
    queue = get_guild_queue(ctx)
    now = datetime.now()
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Queue', colour = discord.Colour.blue())
    if len(queue) == 0:
        value='The queue is empty!'
    else:
        entries = []
        for entry in queue:
            joined = datetime.strptime(entry['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
            wait_min = (now-joined).seconds / 60

            if entry['msg']:
                entries.append('**{}** *({:.0f} min)*: {}'
                               .format(entry['name'], wait_min, entry['msg']))
            else:
                entries.append('**{}** *({:.0f} min)*'
                               .format(entry['name'], wait_min))
        value='\n'.join(entries)

    name = 'Users in the queue ({})'.format(len(queue))
    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

What it currently looks like:
[image]

The goal:
[image]

Comment: There's a ton of things different between the goal/current version, could you be more specific? The line spacing? Indentation? "current turn"? Queue numbering?

Comment: it's in the second paragraph
'Goal: Add index values in front and an indent before the username. Also, add a line spacing in between each entry.'
do let me know if that isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Indenting can be achieved by simply adding some amount of spaces in front of the entries. If this doesn't work (Discord may truncate leading space), try using a tab character:

```py
entries.append('\t**{}** *....[truncated]
                ^^
```

For the index, I'd use the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which gives yields a tuple of the index and element when given an iterator as input. Here's a simple example using a print function, which can be applied to your case.

```py
for index, entry in enumerate(queue):
    # add one as index starts at 0
    print(index + 1, entry)
```

Comment: I know in Python, you can use spaces, but I'm not sure if it's because it goes to Discord or if it's because I'm using Repl.it, but the spaces doesn't work for me.

As for the index, do I just switch out

'for entry in queue:' with 'for index, entry in enumerate(queue):'
since I'm not using the print function but rather append, I was hoping to show it in the code I have

Comment: The new edit gives me the error 'IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple'
and the enumerate still doesnt allow me to output the index values, i need to change the formatting in the append and format